Footnote within minipage: double mark and single text
I have placed a figure caption inside a minipage environment. My goal is to show a single footnote mark several times within the same caption and to write the footnote text only once under the caption.
In the following MWE, the figure 1 caption is Ok, except the fact that the footnote mark appears only once. Be aware that the mark is an alphabetical character.
The figure 2 caption is not Ok according to my goal. The footmark appears twice (ok), but it's not an alphabetical character, and the mark doesn't appear in the footnote text.
Could someone give me a hint how to fulfill my goal?
Thank you!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.9 \textwidth}
   %\includegraphics[width=5cm]{}
    \captionof{figure}[Blabla]{Usual footnote\footnote{Here is the footnote.} within minipage environment.}
    \label{fig:blabla1}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}

\begin{minipage}{0.9 \textwidth}
   %\includegraphics[width=5cm]{}
    \captionof{figure}[Blabla]{First footnote\footnotemark{}. Second footnote\footnotemark[\value{footnote}] with same mark as the first one.}
    \footnotetext{Here is the footnote text.}
    \label{fig:blabla2}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


You can reference a footnote number with \footref:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{MWE}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.9 \textwidth}
   %\includegraphics[width=5cm]{}
    \captionof{figure}[Blabla]{Usual footnote\footnote{\label{fn:cap}Here is the footnote.} within minipage environment. 
Second footnote\footref{fn:cap}}
    \label{fig:blabla1}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}



Thank you! It works as I expected!

Footnotes in minipage, inserted with \footnote, use the mpfootnote counter, and are displayed with letters, by default. But \footnotemark use the main footnote counter (see, for example, this answer).
I think Ulrike Fischer's answer is the best one, but I would suggest another way. Since the footnote mark is drawn by the \@footnotemark macro you can use it to redraw the last counter. Define an alias, to get rid of the @ char:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastfootnotemark}{\@footnotemark}
\makeatother

Then\lastfootnotemark can be used to insert the last footnote mark.
Example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\title{MWE}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\lastfootnotemark}{\@footnotemark}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{0.9 \textwidth}
   %\includegraphics[width=5cm]{}
    \captionof{figure}[Blabla]{First footnote\footnote{Here is the footnote text.}.
      Second footnote\lastfootnotemark{} with same mark as the first one.}
    \label{fig:blabla2}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}



hyperref won't like this. You are breaking its footnote support. It is generally not a good idea to rely unnecessarly on implementation details.

@UlrikeFischer You right. I didn't know \footref. Your answer is the correct way to do it.
